# Exclude package when creating an android release library build using gradle

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a gradle file that creates a library: It includes some external java code that is used also in other java platforms where it contains some unit test code (located in `./../java-common/src-java/`). I would like to exclude the unit test package when creating the release library and keep that code when creating a debug build or an androidTest (or test) build.

But if I specify to exclude the unit test package in the release build it does the same for the other build types. Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

// This is required to be able to create the javadocs when using java 8
if (JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
            options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
        }
    }
}

android {
    defaultPublishConfig 'release'
    publishNonDefault true
    testBuildType "debug"

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            sourceSets {
                main {
                    java {
                        exclude '**/com/mycompany/util/unittest/**'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += '../../java-common/src-java/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.2.1'
    androidTestCompile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs-unittest')
}

...
```

If I run this configuration the release build is create without the `com/mycompany/util/unittest` but when I try to run the debug build or androidTest (unit test) the build does not includes the required com/mycompany/util/unittest package.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!